# How to view getfacl output in a Row

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions

I can view permissions of all files using:

```
$ getfacl -R .
# file: .
# owner: blueray
# group: blueray
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

# file: first-file.adoc
# owner: blueray
# group: blueray
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--

# file: first-dir
# owner: blueray
# group: blueray
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

How can I see these permissions in a row. Something like:

```
file:first-file.adoc owner: blueray group: blueray user::rw- group::rw- other::r--
dir:first-dir owner: blueray group: blueray user::rwx group::rwx other::r-x
```

Please note that, `getfacl -R .` output mention directory `first-dir` as `file` by saying `file: first-dir`. But it create confusion as meaning of execute (x) is different from file and directory.

**P.S.** I know that there can be more than 6 columns in `getfacl .` output. But the given six will be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output you’re after by removing the hashes and reflowing “paragraphs” while allowing long lines:

```
getfacl -R . | sed 's/^# //' | fmt -w300
```

It’s not clear what you want to do with colons; if you want to replace all `:`  pairs with a single colon, without modifying file names, add the relevant `sed` expression:

```
getfacl -R . | sed -e 's/^# //' -e 's/: /:/' | fmt -w300
```

Note that `getfacl` represents non-printable characters using their octal value (*e.g.* newlines as `\012`), so you might need to post-process the output if you want to re-use it.

I don’t think it’s possible to distinguish files from directories in `getfacl`’s output.